# How does Exchange-to-Exchange binding decouple agents from having to ‘know’ the server queues?

Tags: routes, rabbitmq, message-queue, messaging

I've recently read topic on ["Routing Topologies for Performance and Scalability with RabbitMQ"](http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/01/routing-topologies-for-performance-and-scalability-with-rabbitmq/)  and one thing that I cannot understand why it makes difference to have private exchange that is bound to public topic exchange, and how does it eliminate need to know about servers queues?

Currently I'm just publishing to public topic exchange and don't need to know if there are some queues bound ot it. If queue isn't there the message will dead-lettered.

As I understand with Ex-to-Ex binding I should expect the same behaviour, if the queue isn't there, the message will be dead-lettered.

Comment: Note that you need to setup _alternate exchanges_  to implement some sort of dead-lettering at the routing level https://www.rabbitmq.com/ae.html

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't need it"? Dead lettering works on queues, messages are dead lettered when their TTL expires for example, or the message is rejected by a consumer.

When a message is not routable, whether sent to an exchange with queue bindings or exchange to exchange bindings, the message is dropped, unless you have either:

- set the mandatory flag when the message was published, so the message is returned to the client
- set alternate exchanges so the message is routed to a diff path

Answer (score 0):

The only time you need to know about a queue is when you use the default exchange as you need to set the routing key as the queue name.

This article is not an exhaustive treatise on routing topologies and I find it quite unclear. Personally I use exchange to exchange bindings with a shared exchange where messages are published to, and private exchanges for consumers. The shared exchange is a fanout and then the private exchanges are free to use any type of exchange they want, without affecting the shared exchange configuration.

Publishers declare the shared exchange and publish to it and consumers declare their own private exchange, configured as they like and bind to the shared exchange. You don't get errors on exchange declaration as only the publisher is responsible for declaring the shared exchange. As a cookie cutter pattern it is nicely decoupled and can be customised further depending on the use case.

Then with policies you can set up alternate exchanges and dead letter exchange rules.